# CakePHP 2.x HABTM join table with extra fields

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.0, cakephp-2.1

In a CakePHP 2.3.1 project, I have a typical HABTM relationship between two classes, but I want to add an extra field to the join table. in the Cakephp docs http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/saving-your-data.html#saving-habtm. It says that's possible but it doesn't say how :

> Also note that if you want to add more fields to the join (when it was created or meta information) this is possible with HABTM join tables...

(I don't wanna use the hasmany solution it's not suitable for my case, as I need to have the multiselection possibility in my form).

Answer (score 0):

Yes definitely you can add fields in HABTM Relation ship in CakePHP 2.X

Check out the below sample HABTM Relationship:

```
var $hasAndBelongsToMany = array(
    'Category' => array(
        'className' => 'Category',
        'joinTable' => 'user_categories',
        'foreignKey' => 'user_id',
        'associationForeignKey' => 'category_id',
        'with' => 'UserCategory',
        'unique' => 'true',
        'fields' => 'User.name',
        'order' => '',
        'limit' => '',
        'offset' => '',
        'finderQuery' => '',
        'deleteQuery' => '',
        'insertQuery' => ''
    )

);
```

In the above "fields" option u can mention your join fields if any and it will work.

Comment: Can you elaborate more please. For example in the 'Users/add.ctp' view how the extra field to be added is represented ?

Comment: yes, please elaborate and perhaps provide a link. I'd like to know how this is done